# Are there truly alien Star Trek species with races?

Tags: star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, races, star-trek

Certainly there are cases,  but I'm excluding cases where the alien's features (mostly skin color) match those of the actor.

And of course there are these guys from Cheron in the TOS episode "Let That Be Your Last Battlefield" where it's the central plot point:

[image]

But are there other cases where an alien race was designed arbitrarily to just happen to have divergent ethnicities?  For example, some aliens are green, and others are blue, and it's not part of the plot?

Clarification:  "Not part of the plot" doesn't mean it can't be mentioned.   It just means the shouldn't be a case where the difference exists as the central theme or plot-driving element, such as "Let That Be Your Last Battlefield" where the whole point of the episode is to comment on racism -- so of course they had to create a species with races for that.

Comment: @N_Soong:  huh?   There are white and black and Asian Vulcans (even though they don't have Asia) but those fit into the first category.

Comment: What does "truly alien" mean here?  Do you mean alien species with a lot of makeup and/or facial prosthetics?

Comment: @Praxis: I'm basically trying to rule out cases where the variations in the ethnicities of the actors are just bleeding through into the aliens' appearances.

Comment: Oh wait - now I get the question - Star Trek alien races which have sub-races within the species: gotcha!

Comment: @N_Soong Ah, you too thought the question was about racing at first.

Comment: Could you rephrase the title question?  "races with races" is confusing.  I think, after reading the expanded version, I get your point, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Also, for example, would the Xindi count?  Since they all evolved on the same planet?  Or do you specifically mean (I think this is your intent) a species with a subspecies?

Comment: @Tango:  I happen to like a wording with a hook,  but if it's really that confusing,  give a suggestion.      Yes,  looking ethnicities within a species,  not multiple species from the same planet.

Comment: Would the [Kes](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kes_(government)) and [Prytt](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Prytt_Alliance) count?

Comment: @N_Soong I don't know. We know black Vulcans (Tuvok for example), but I can't recall any black Romulans. Might it be the result of some age-old racial hatred/conflict? May the Romulans be the descendents of "nazi" Vulcans?

Comment: @mg30rg: For what it's worth, [Romulan Commander Sirol](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Sirol) was played by a [black actor](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_Mack), even though as a Romulan, his complexion did not appear to be particularly dark.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - We were (at least I was) talking about the racism of the Romulans, not racism of the casting crew. And even if the artist was black, his makeup made him look like "white" Romulans/Vulcans (unlike Tuvok). - Also I was kind of joking here - but I either did not remember commander Sirol or did not recognise he was played by a black actor.

Comment: @mg30rg: Well, I was referring to the question whether there are "actually" any (e.g.) black Vulcans, or whether that is just the actors appearance "bleeding through", and listed a similar Romulan example (while I agree he apears rather white, it is not clear on the photo whether that impression is created by the lighting to some extent, or whether his complexion is actually modified by makeup a lot). And of course, there is no guarantee that e.g. facial features that are more typical for black humans than e.g. for white ones couldn't be combined with other skin colours in Romulans. ...

Comment: ... Therefore, the Romulans we see might not be as racially homogeneous as it seems at first, even though they might feature the same skin colour.

Comment: @mg30rg Well, with the Vulcans at least, we know that they can interbreed with humans. The same with Human-Klingons. So Vulcans can't really be a different species (at least in TNG+; TOS did mention that Spock was "engineered", not bred), and Klingons either. Now, remember how Klingons treat the other "races" (human, vulcan...)? They're definitely racist, if you ask me! Klingon blood my ... :D

Comment: @Luaan - On the Klingon-human interbreed; it could easily be a result of the ["superhuman" program](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Klingon_augment_virus) applied to Klingons. On Vulcan-human interbreed - if memory serves me right - in case of Spock the "technique of interbred had to be developed" (read it 15 years ago and on my native language - maybe, but not surely in "Time For Yesterday" - so I'm not sure about it), so it might be a mainstream operation by the time of TNG.

Comment: @mg30rg I think there were a few references in the later series where the "hybrids" were conceived naturally, but I can't find any. Even ENT has human-vulcan hybrid be a result of genetic engineering. However, Deanna Troi seems to be perfectly natural, and B'Elanna may also be. There was even a match between Worh and Deanna. But you're right, it's hard to tell for certain - after all, out-of-universe, the writers probably didn't know much about biology. Maybe they are a different species, but more along the line of horse-donkey than human-chimpanzee :D

Comment: Hey everyone, my restriction on 'not a plot point' was really meant to eliminate the white/black black/white type-case where the entire point of the episode was to comment on racism.   It doesn't mean it can't be mentioned that there are different races.   It just shouldn't be the central theme.  More like, is there an alien species that has the same diversity as humans, without it being the theme of the week.

Comment: @Luaan - What I've tried to express is that I think almost all Star Trek humanoid species have "nearly" compatible genome (which has a possible explanation in TNG if I recall it right), and there are "simple" treatments making interbreeding possible. Now, "simple" is a relative term. XX. century humans call a caesarean section quite routine, but who knows, what "simple" means for XXIV. century people capable of altering the genome of a living organism? Maybe there are "interbreed pills" you must take on a daily basis to be able to give birth to a half-klingon baby. That sounds almost...

Comment: @Luaan - (...continued) natural, like taking vitamins for pregnant women. (You wouldn't even call it a treatment, would you?) Except for those wouldn't be vitamins but mutagenes temporally changing your phenotype (genotype?) to make the pregnancy possible.

Comment: How do you know it's an @ThePopMachine question?  By counting the number of comments. ;-)

Comment: @Praxis:   ha!!!!!!!!

Comment: Twi'leks come in five different colors, and red is highly prized because it's rare. Oh, wait... dang. Wrong universe.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : In all seriousness though, your Star Trek questions have been extremely thought-provoking and have generated a lot of lively discussion, re-energizing the Trek community on SFF.  Kudos. :-)

Comment: It seems like this question is predicated on a fundamental misunderstanding of what race IS. Am I wrong? If not, perhaps the question would be better phrased in a different way?

Comment: @N_Soong : Television series and film titles are italicized, while individual episodes titles are placed between quotation marks (they are like chapters in a book or papers in a journal), as per the *Chicago Manual of Style*... ;-)

Comment: @Praxis Whoops - my bad!

Comment: @N_Soong : No worries.  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis:  why added their names?   "These guys" was referring to their species,  not those two guys specifically.  That's what matters in this context.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Actually, N_Soong added them first, along with changes to your episode title formatting. Then I rolled back his edit to restore your original formatting of the episode titles (which I felt was correct).  Then I added in the character names that N_Soong added. But I agree that the species is what matters.  I'll roll back all the edits. :-)

Comment: @Praxis, well do we know the name of the species?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : They come from the planet Cheron.  So...Cheronites?  Cheronians?

Comment: @Praxis - they are... MY CHERONA.

Comment: @Omegacron : Nice.

Answer (score 27):

## Caitians

[image]

A Caitian Federation Council Representative (Star Trek IV)

[image]

A Caitian Admiral (Star Trek IV)

## Disputable:

### Tiburonians

[image]

Crewman T'Lor, a male Tiburonian (2373)

[image]

Dr. Sevrin, a male Tiburonian (2269)

### Tellarites

[image: Enterprise version]

*Enterprise* version

[image]

*TOS* Tellarite.

As you can see, the two look quite a bit different - perhaps different races?

Comment: +1...but I think this would be like saying that Klingons from TOS are a different race from film era and TNG era Klingons.  The makeup simply improved.  In the case of Klingons they decided to do a retcon explanation.  In the case of Tellarites (and Trills below), there was no in-universe explanation given for the changes in makeup.

Comment: I really think this is the same as the other cases mentioned.  Differing makeup between TOS and a later series doesn't count because it's probably not supposed to exist in-universe

Comment: @N_Soong : The first sentence of the question rules Vulcans out....

Comment: @N_Soong:  if they didn't match the actors, it would,  but since they do, it's more like a byproduct of the real world than a design point of the aliens.  Or at least we can't know.

Comment: Catians...love it!  :-)

Comment: @ThePopMachine I've got Catians now!

Comment: @N_Soong deserves another vote for Catians!

Comment: Apparently it's Ca***i***tian.  Do we know that different color fur means different ethnicity?   (Now we're treading into complex territory because the concept of race for humans is largely historical and cultural, not well-defined genetically)

Comment: @ThePopMachine they've also got different ears...

Comment: @N_Soong : I like the Catian (or Caitian) example because the makeup work is from the same period.  The Tiburonians probably fall into the Klingon / Tellarite / Trill retconning...

Comment: @Praxis possibly, although IMHO if there isn't an in-universe reason provided like in the case of the Klingons, then it's fair game!

Comment: Yes,  I agree the Caitians are the best offering so far,  but it's also a funny case because they are clearly modeled after the concept of breeds of cat.

Comment: I'm not sure whether "looks different to us" necessarily indicates "the aliens species consists of multiple races". I'm imagining some alien showing pictures of a black-haired and a blonde-haired human and saying, "these look different, so they are of different races" when in point of fact the examples chosen are full siblings :-) Not that race in humans is a precisely-defined concept in biological terms, but for starters the differing traits need to be observably associated with separate lines of inheritance.

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree that we can't necessarily conclude that they are distinct races - these are species we haven't even met yet.  But based on our current knowledge, I'd say it's a reasonable stab in the dark :)

Comment: Other than extra hair the ears look the same to me

Comment: It could well be that the obvious phenotypic distinctions in alien species are not that obvious to us (as it is said e.g. for westerners vs. asians (both ways) that "the others" all look alike while "our folks" are clearly distinguishable; I'm not sure how true that is though). So a Tellarite might say about what we consider his twin brother on first sight: "Don't you see the earlobe-shapes? He's clearly from that other continent .." - And another species asked about the differences between Uhura, Zulu and Kirk might say "Hm, I don't know. Are you trying to fool me and one of them is male?"

Answer (score 17):

## The two guys on the right.

[image]

This is from *Star Trek VI*.

I have no idea what species they are, but (a) they are truly alien, (b) their differences do not have to do with the skin colour of the actors, (c) their differences do not have to do with make-up retconning, and (d) their differences are not a plot point.

Comment: I'm literally lying in bed cracking up over the fact your answer is **the two guys on the right**

Comment: @ThePopMachine : My job here is done. ;-)

Comment: Apart from their height and markings on the forehead (either of which might be related to the ages of individuals in a single 'race'), what's the difference between them?  In fact, now I think about it, the markings might simply be tattoos or cosmetic 'war paint'..

Comment: I was thinking of the forehead markings.  Didn't seem like tattoos to me, but who knows?

Comment: That’s the problem with the question. If differences inside species are not a plot point, they are usually not explained at all, which implies that we simply don’t know whether they make up different races and not, e.g. different genders or just an ordinary variation. Besides that, it’s impossible to conclude from appearance to ethnicity anyway as that requires knowledge about the culture and history (i.e. why does human’s color of skin matter but color of hair or eyes not). If that’s not a plot point, it’s unlikely to ever hear about it.

Comment: Hey everyone, my restriction on 'not a plot point' was really meant to eliminate the white/black black/white type-case where the entire point of the episode was to comment on racism.   It doesn't mean it can't be mentioned that there are different races.   It just shouldn't be the central theme.  More like, is there an alien species that has the same diversity as humans, without it being the theme of the week.

Answer (score 13):

There are many examples.

Vulcans: The Vulcans have large racial diversity. TOS's Spock, VOY's Tuvok, and ENT's T'Pol all appear to be different ethnicity. Furthermore, the Romulans are still biologically similar enough to the main Vulcans to be inter-compatible, but they're distinct enough that certain medical treatments won't work the same, as mentioned in DS9's Inter Arma i'm not typing the rest of that name. If standard medicine has to be double checked for different ethnicities, you have an extremely diverse species. Also, most Romulans are white or slightly tan colored. However, in DS9's "Improbable Cause", we saw a black Romulan woman who worked for the Tal Shiar.

Andorians: The Andorians have a fair amount of diversity, but it seems to be skewed. The most frequent ethnic group we saw was the blue-skinned Andorians, such as Shran. We also saw in TNG's "The Offspring" that green Andorians exist. We saw the Aenar in Enterprise, who are blind, telepathic, and white. This species likely will have a genetic bottleneck, as their population is dropping, and the Aenar are extinct. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Aenar

Trill: as mentioned by @Mr Lister, though most trill are the spotted kind, there's also a forehead ridged kind.

Bajorans: as mentioned in the memory alpha page, there were dark skinned Bajorans. This was never a plot point. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran

Probable Examples:
Ocampans: We know that some of the Ocampa left after their world was transformed into a desert. The two groups lost contact shortly thereafter, and were seperated for at least 300 years. At a rate of complete population replacement every 9 years, the two groups have been seperated for well over 30 generations, which would be enough for some genetic distinctness to emerge, especially since the seperatist group was only a few hundred people. The small population would likely have a fair amount of genetic shift, enough for some distinctions to emerge.  https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ocampa

Jem'Hadar: We know that after Sisko mined the aperture of the Bajoran wormhole, the dominion had to start cloning Jem'Hadar locally in the alpha quadrant. These Jem'Hadar were apparently breed with different demands in mind. This may be the only example of deliberate artificial racial diversity. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jem_Hadar

Kobali: Probably the most extreme example in terms of variety. This species grows its population by salvaging the dead of other species, modifying the dead to meet their biological specs, and being a race of zombies. The process isn't perfect, and as a result, people retain enough origional DNA to be individually identifiable. As a result, the Kobali have the racial diversity of the variation between several different species. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kobali

Comment: Upvoted because I think the Vulcans are a good TV-canon example that other answers have overlooked. However, ethnicity is social/cultural, whereas race is biological.

Comment: I think the comment "I'm excluding cases where the alien's features (mostly skin color) match those of the actor" should exclude Vulcans, since the only racial differences we saw were ones that match different ethnicities of the actors that played them. The greenish Andorian from "The Offspring" (which could have been blue, hard to tell in the dim light) was probably just a makeup decision, but it might be retconned as being part [Aenar](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Aenar), like the Andorian/Aenar mix seen in [Talla](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Talla).

Comment: Excellent point about the Jem'Hadar, and the difference between Alphas & Gammas WAS a plot point in one of the DS9 episodes. I think it was the one where the shuttlecraft got miniaturized and the Defiant was taken over.

Comment: I just amended the list with the Kobali.

Comment: More romulan diversity was just added.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté race is as much a social construct as it is biological. To see what I mean, try to come up with a consistent, purely biological (or, if you want to be precise, try purely *phenotypic*) definition of any given (RL) race (that doesn't misclassify people of other races) *or* of the concept itself. The difference is not whether something is defined by biology vs society/culture but by *ancestry* vs cultural reference points. The difference is subtle but significant.

Answer (score 12):

The Andorians have a completely separate sub species in the Aenar and, even within the main Andorian species there are vast differences in the hue of blue they show.

Now a lot of it is to do with retconning but many are of the same time period of Trek shows.
Quick edit here (differences in skin colour could just be an Andorian tan but, you can see obvious physical differences in the antennae of them also)

[image: Very dark blue]
[image: Near purple]
[image: Shran: Bright blue]
[image: Near grey/washed out blue]
[image: Between Shran and grey]

Comment: Aren't the differences in human "races" also just kind of a tan?  Even if permanent, it is generally pigmentation that is responsible for the different skin appearances.

Comment: Nope, I added that to clarify, just in case someone jokingly replied "That's just a tan" lol. A white person will tan but return to their base colour after time. A person of only Chinese decent can also tan but their base colour is still different to regular Joe Irish of European only ancestry. Now the reason that I mention the physical traits is that some of our own races have definite physical differences; be it the epicanthic fold or nose/lip differences.

Comment: Looking at the other answers, I think this answer should put more emphasis on the point that it was, for once, a plot point that the Aenar were different.

Comment: I thought of that but as a sub species, as opposed to race, would it fit?

Comment: @user001: What is the difference between "sub-species" and "race"? Both seem to refer to a genetic offshoot of common ancestors that has developed its own, slightly different genetic traits. The only difference I can see is that "sub-species" sounds more science-fiction-ey.

Comment: Not really, the Aenar have major adaptions that the general Andorians do not (ie are blind and telepathic). Their common ancestry and (apparent) ease of interbreeding would lead me to calling them a subspecies rather than a new species. 
What we call race here are, by and large cosmetic distinctions. The differences between both are, indeed, fluid but, in this instance I would call the Aenar a true sub-species as opposed to a race of Andorian.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : My understanding of the question is that it is *not* looking for an ethnicity or sub-species that is a plot point.  The Aenar were a major plot point...

Comment: Very true, another reason why I thought that the Andorian example was good as it shows distinct skin pigmentation (such as we have here) and it's not a plot point as it is just not an issue (which is how it should be)

Comment: @Praxis: True, though as per the OP's comments, the lower limit seems to be that [it's not just the actor's human apperance "bleeding through"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102522/are-there-truly-alien-star-trek-species-with-races/102529?noredirect=1#comment236160_102522), while the upper limit is that the [plot should not revolve around the racial difference, yet the difference may well be mentioned](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102522/are-there-truly-alien-star-trek-species-with-races/102529?noredirect=1#comment236270_102522). The Aenar were a borderline case with ...

Comment: ... respect to the upper limit, as the plot made their difference somewhat important, though arguably that difference was IMHO somewhat forgettable. Finding blind, white-skinned, telepathic Andorians simply sounds more spectacular than finding ... an up-to-then unknown "tribe" of Andorians. In other words, and as opposed to the Bele/Lokai example from the question, their being different was not so indispensable for the story.

Comment: The telepathic points were the major plot points, however, as they were used by Romulans to control the ships remotely

Comment: @user001: Screenplay-defined technobabble. Had they not been telepathic, the drone would have been controlled some other way. It's not like we hadn't seen [rather similar technologies used with non-telepaths on Star Trek before](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Interface_%28episode%29). As I wrote above, making the Aenar telepathic sounds more spectacular, but doesn't really change the plot. Again, compare with the Bele/Lokai episode - it would not have made any sense, had Bele and Lokai not been naturally different.

Comment: I have no problem expanding the answer to cater to this.
 A bit of a lead from @ThePopMachine on how stringent he wants to be would be good in this instance

Comment: @user001 Human races express far more difference than skin color, though. Vasculature varies greatly, as do fat deposit location and composition, among a host of other differences; skin color is just the most visible expression. "Race" is such a charged word that this is difficult to discuss (but somehow it is OK to say things like "X's have a higher incidence of cardeovascular disease" -- *even though the color is not relevant* and totally overlooks the structural differences that make this so). Anyway, "race" is tricky, both to identify and meaningfully express.

Comment: Perhaps it is useful to subdivide this into "sub-species" (concrete genetic differences that are medically observable), "ethnicity" (a cultural phenomenon which is very often, but not always, sub-species related), and "nationality" (collective political affiliation which is often, but not always, ethnically based). "Race" is just too hard to discuss, identify, or assign meaning to. Especially since humans in the real world and aliens in the Trek world tend to mix it up a lot (apparently variety will maintain its spot as the greatest aphrodesiac far into the future).

Comment: I should have made my point clearer.  I was trying to hint at the fact that there are no different human races either.  I understand that differences in humans are genetic but they do not constitute a different race.  The same could be true for what you call a tan with the Andorians, even if the antennae are different.

Answer (score 10):

## The Breen

The Breen consist of **four races**, who all come from the planet Breen.  We never see their differing appearances on screen because they all wear the same encounter suits:

[image]

I picked this example especially because the fact that there are different races of Breen is never a plot point.

Comment: Links or it didn't happen.

Comment: Interesting.   Kind of a cop out on their part given we specifically never see a Breen.  Also, what's the source of the "four races" notion?   Do we know whether "races" meant species or ethnicities?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Mostly post-DS9 Beta material, which fleshed out a comment in the episodes about "not being sure that they are all the same species".  And so I believe they are different species rather than ethnicities.  I posted this mostly for fun, really. :-)

Comment: Dominion War series of books no?

Comment: @user001 : I believe so.

Comment: Five races.  You forgot ["Princess Leia in disguise in Jabba's palace."](http://www.jeditemplearchives.com/galleries/2011/Review_PrincessLeiaBoushhTSC/Review_PrincessLeiaBoushhTSC_stillA.JPG)

Answer (score 8):

According to Memory Alpha, [Trills](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trill) qualify.

> Most Trills are distinguished by two rows of spots going down each side of their bodies, from forehead to toe. Their skin color could vary.

And it has photos of different specimens...

[image]
[image]

Now while the differences in skin tones in the photos aren't very convincing, they do have different markings on their faces.

Comment: The appearance of trills was retconned because the actress who played Jadzia Dax looked better with spots than with a forehead piece.

Comment: Yes,  this is more like the change in appearance of the Klingons (later retcon-explained) or the Cardassian helmet thing.

Comment: Hm, so the "Their skin color could vary" in the quote doesn't count?

Comment: Speaking of the Klingons, the (apocryphal, as always) novel [Forged In Fire](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Forged_in_Fire) explains the "original" ridged-forehead un-transportable Trill being caused by the Augment virus.

Comment: Ah, Jadzia... The trill so beautiful she caused an entire species to spontaneously evolve spots and change their skull structure.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes,  the Kazon appear to have races not explained by that of the actors or makeup differences over time.

[Michael Jonas](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Jonas)' Kazon contact, [Lorrum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lorrum) in "Dreadnought" is decided pale in color rather than the usual red.

[image]

[image]